# Reshape JSON with jq to expand each object into multiple rows

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a database of resumes in json format that I want to reshape so that each row corresponds to a person's employment history at a given company:

personid, company_name, start_date, end_date

However, running the following jq command

`{personid:.personid, company_name: .experience[].company.name, sdate: .experience[].start_date, edate: .experience[].end_date}`

produces the cartesian product of all the fields (3 jobs x 3 fields). For example, a person who has held 3 jobs at 3 different companies in the past looks like this after running the jq command above:

```
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2020-06","edate":null}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2020-06","edate":null}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2020-06","edate":"2017-07"}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2016-10","edate":null}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2016-10","edate":null}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2016-10","edate":"2017-07"}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2017-05","edate":null}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2017-05","edate":null}
{"id":"abc123","companyname":"companyA","sdate":"2017-05","edate":"2017-07"}
```

There are 9 entries for CompanyB and CompanyC each but I truncated the output above for brevity.

I think I need to use the group_by() command, but I've been unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the original data, my guess is that you get the cartesian product because you are iterating three times (`.experience[]`) within the object construction. You might want to pull out the iteration, maybe save it in a variable, and reference that instead:

```
.experience[] as $experience | {
  personid: .personid,
  company_name: $experience.company.name,
  sdate: $experience.start_date,
  edate: $experience.end_date
}
```

Depending on the outer structure of your construction, also the other way around may be appropriate, ie. storing the `.person` field instead in a variable:

```
.personid as $id | .experience[] | {
  personid: $id,
  company_name: .company.name,
  sdate: .start_date,
  edate: .end_date
}
```

Comment: "Without seeing the original data, my guess is that" can be omitted. It's definitely because `.experience[]` is used three times.